# Send Form Content to Endpoint in Different App Django

Tags: python, django

Say I have an app called `App1` - inside of which there is a template that has a form with name and email.

Now, say I have an app called `App2` - that has an endpoint which takes in a name and email and sends an email to that email.

Now, I want to combine the two, so that I can make the form contents go to the endpoint in `App2` on submit, thus sending an email to the email in the form.

**How would I do this? Would it be better to just put them in the same app? When would someone use 2 apps over 1?**

Does this make sense? Thanks for your help!

Comment: IMHO It is not a big deal unless you want to make reusable apps which can be used in other django projects.

Comment: So, you suggest doing it all in one app?